# Guice inject in servlet

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm fresh new in Google Guice framework and i have a question regarding injecting in guice servlet and using RequestScope. Ok let me give some example from my code just to make the things clearly.

I have a bean class for example Bean ..

```
@RequestScope
public class Bean {
    private String user;
    private String pass;

    // constructor which is @inject 

    // getters and setters
}
```

Here i've got a servlet

```
@Singleton
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        .... some code 
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
        ValidUser validUser = injector.getInstance(ValidUser.class)
        // Here i got the below exception
    }
}



com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No scope is bound to com.google.inject.servlet.RequestScoped.
  at Bean.class while locating Bean
```

It's interesting here that servlet scope is singleton as we know. 
And also how can i get from the http request - Bean instance?? because as far as i understand after a instance of a Bean class is injected it goes in the http request, right?

Any help or example is welcome.
Thanks
Br

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're creating and using an `Injector` *inside* the `doGet` method on your servlet... it has no chance to be aware of scope or of the current request or anything!

Guice Servlet requires that you set up all requests to go through the `GuiceFilter` and that you create a subclass of `GuiceServletContextListener` that creates the `Injector` that your whole application will use. This is all described in Guice user guide in the [Servlets](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets) section.

Once you've done that, you can `@Inject` things in to your `MainServlet` (even using an `@Inject` annotated constructor). To get a request scoped instance of `Bean` inside the servlet, you'd need to inject a `Provider<Bean>` (since `Bean` has a smaller scope than the singleton servlet). Within a request, you can call `beanProvider.get()` to get the `Bean` for the current request.

Note that servlets are singletons because that's how they work in the normal Java servlet world as well... they're each only created once per application and that single instance is used for all requests to that servlet.

Comment: Wow, this is a good explanation but a little bit hard for a new Guice user like me, anyway thanks for the hint.